# Unity URP - Batching GPU instanced objects with same material/mesh not working

Tags: unity

I have 100 units (exact same prefab) on screen. The material is a URP Lit using a texture with GPU instancing enabled. Why is it not batching? Am I missing something?

I also noticed it requires 3-4 batches per model, why is this?

See screenshots for stats and info.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How does your prefab hierarchy look?

Comment: @Tordin Some inactive alternate models, and a weapon. I have tried remove every single mesh except the main model, to exclude that as an issue.

Comment: Wild guess: Are you setting the color of the units (or any other property of the renderer or its material) through a script?

Comment: @Philipp No I made sure I didnt. Even if I just put the bare models without any scripts attached into the scene, they will not batch.

Comment: @Philipp ... Crap, missed something here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html. Apparently "SkinnedMeshRenderer is not supported."

Answer (score 1):

From [docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html)

> SkinnedMeshRenderer is not supported